# Improving Pytesseract img to text output

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am extracting text from img (based on variable url). After modifying last image and using pytesseract, the output is not consistent.

My main goal is to read any of the following words under "Gauja: ", which could cointain:

1. Mafia
2. Ballas
3. Vagos
4. VLA
5. GSF
6. Nang

```py
def url_to_text(vp):
    #response = requests.get('http://www.lsgyvenimas.lt/sig/sig.php?name=Robis_Lomani')
    response = requests.get('http://www.lsgyvenimas.lt/sig/sig.php?name=' + vp)
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    width, height = img.size
    new_size = width*10, height*10
    img = img.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)
    #img.show()
    img = img.convert("L")
    img = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 200 else 255, '1')
    img.show()
    imagetext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    #print(imagetext)
    return imagetext
```

Output images after processing:
https://gyazo.com/6cd9bcf77d67ee0fce93a72c7dd6f4cf
https://gyazo.com/5430d8b504a9abc11ddae45c079443c3

On Robis_Lomani case Mafia is read

On Daumanas_Klimas case Matla is read

text output on Daumantas_Klimas

```
Daumantas_Klimas

A TAP Raudomas: O lygiu
ae gad ee EUR - bauja: Matla

Banke: 7.311.276 aa) Qarbas: Oyleris
```

Original image: http://www.lsgyvenimas.lt/sig/sig.php?name=Daumantas_Klimas

How I should continue processing image to get my outputs consistent?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message in question as text, not image, not link to external file. Downvote.

Comment: You can improve your question following this gude : How do I ask a good question? : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies, however I will leave links to any images as I cant describe them in text

Answer (score 0):

My image was in Lithuanian and after reading article in more depth, image_to_string can have language preference, hence in my instance I had to use:

```
imagetext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='lit')
```

instead of

```
imagetext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Article (https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/?fbclid=IwAR0vn2MQNGYpTVVQQTG6r5MDXo26UIgNYb-eY_W-FVvgHSTSJeINaBwdLCA) 
search for language in Other PyTesseract Options